# Bad character in AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I make an AJAX call and in response, I return some lines of text using ASP.NET.

But sometimes the response does not show completely in IE7 (but OK in Firefox).

I think there is a bad character in response.
Is there a list of bad characters or any rule to create standard response?

Comment: Can you show the server side code you use to generate the response?

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap any text in the xml node with `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`